# 403 when requesting private gemfury package for install

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, gem-fury

How can I install private packages from gemfury from my own account.

I'm getting a 403 when trying to install a private package from my gemfury account.

```
yarn --verbose
...
verbose 0.22845086 Found configuration file "/Users/chrisbest/Documents/test-client/.yarnrc".
...
verbose 0.234278553 current time: 2020-08-26T17:06:01.680Z
[1/5]   Validating package.json...
[2/5]   Resolving packages...
verbose 0.454187488 Performing "GET" request to "https://npm.fury.io/testorg/@testscope%2fbutton".
verbose 1.61564947 Request "https://npm.fury.io/testorg/@testscope%2fbutton" finished with status code 403.
verbose 1.630735964 Error: Couldn't find package "@testscope/button@^1.0.0" required by "test-client@0.1.0" on the "npm" registry.
```

I have a trial on Gemfury with an organization account and an individual account that is a collaborator.

I have published a package that I can see through the web UI called `button` (I have also tried @lhpublic/button`).

I have added the scoped registry url to the .yarnrc file listed as having been found above `"@testscope:registry" "https://npm.fury.io/testorg/"`, and yarn does make the request to the url I specified.

I have set `npm config set always-auth true` and logged in to the registry using my gemfury collaborator account `npm login --registry=https://npm.fury.io/testorg` and in ~/.npmrc I see

```
always-auth=true
//npm.fury.io/:_authToken={my token}
```

I also see a 403 when running `yarn --verbose info @testscope/button`, while `yarn --verbose info button` successfully returns info for the unrelated `button` package on the public npm registry.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've omitted the URL trailing slash in your `npm login` command. If you run the command as:

```
$ npm login --registry="https://npm.fury.io/testorg/"
```

npm will correctly save the credentials for your Gemfury repo in ~/.npmrc:

```
//npm.fury.io/testorg/:_authToken={my token}
```

Ref: https://gemfury.com/help/private-yarn/#scoped-packages